# Crystal reports custom background color

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

problem definition:
having data with symbolic colors (i.e each teacher is noted with a color)
in `DataGridView` displaying a simple `SELECT` query result, I managed to color each row with its teacher's color
using visual studio 2012 and crystal report for VS 13.0.5

```
public void setColor() {
        int index = this.Dgv.Columns["color"].Index;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.Dgv.Rows)
        {
            System.Drawing.ColorConverter cc = new System.Drawing.ColorConverter();
            System.Drawing.Color c = (System.Drawing.Color)cc.ConvertFromString(row.Cells[index].Value.ToString());
            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = c;
        }
        this.Dgv.ClearSelection();
    }
```

I'd like to get a similarly styled report in crystal report but I'm having problems with color manipulation, the far I could get was alternating row color as many articles online help me through.
crystal report color issues I've found while searching were solved by applying the logic in a formula but in my case the colors are within the bound dataset (color values like "WHITE", "#FF0092" etc)

I thought of changing how the color is stored to (rr,gg,bb) to make use of the Color function in crystal report, would the function accept the string instead of 3 parameters?

to wrap my question up:
- is it possible to achieve the same level of color-control in crystal reports as in C#?
- is it possible to string-manipulate the (rr,gg,bb) string to extract the 3 needed parameters?

any pointers are appreciated
please include explanation since I'm a CR newbie
thank you

Comment: You have to create formula, parsing your dataset color field and returning CR compatible color.

Answer (score 0):

Not certain I understand the 2nd part.  You can definitely achieve total color control.

Try a formula called Color.  Define it as:
if {Teacher}='teacher1' then color(1,2,3)
else if ...

for each of the teachers.

A CASE statement will work as well.

Then in the Section Expert for the desired section select color, then 'more' to get to the formula expert.  Simply insert the name of the formula you just created - @color

Comment: but I don't know what color is for each teacher to use in `color(?, ? ,?)`.. it's from the database query

Comment: Oh! NEAT.I think that's actually really interesting.
I'm hoping your report is grouped by teacher. IF not, it likely needs to be but I'd have to think on that.

You want a sub report placed in the group header for the group by Teacher Name section.

Link the sub report to the teacher ID.
In the sub report select the RGB value.  Create a formula that has a shared stringvar.  MUST BE SHARED.

Comment: Apologies - I hit enter before finishing.

Place that formula on your report.  In the main report body suppress the subreport so it isn't seen.

create a formula (in the main report). Name it what you like but the content MUST be
shared stringvar ABC
 
where ABC is the exact same name for the shared stringvar you have in the sub report.  This is how you pass a parameter from the sub to the main.

You can now use that formula as I described earlier.

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar. I want to store the color in my table (RGB) and have Crystal take the field and read it to determine the color: Color(Highlighting) is this possible?  I'm already using a formula IF Highlighting = (0,191,255) then Color(0,191,255). But, I don't want to create a formula for every color. Any thoughts?